# LocalStorage help, (working todo list)

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, local-storage

Im new on saving stuff on the web (cookie, localstorage) with more, And this is my current code

```
    var c = 1;
function addText(){
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var node = document.createElement("P");
    node.setAttribute('id', 'anchor'+c);
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(input);
    node.appendChild(textnode);

    var removenode = document.createElement("input");
    removenode.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    removenode.setAttribute('value', 'X');
    removenode.setAttribute("onclick", "removeText('anchor"+c+"')");
    node.appendChild(removenode);
    c++;
    document.getElementById('do').appendChild(node);
}

function removeText(item){
    var child=document.getElementById(item);
    document.getElementById('do').removeChild(child);
}
```

I wonder if someone could help me out with localstorage in this code? would love the help, I have read here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp and other places but I don't really understand how to implent it to my code.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can save to LocalStorage by using the `localStorage.setItem(key, value);` function and remove the item by using the `localStorage.removeItem(key);` function. [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cheejyg/Y83mQ/4/).

Javascript:

```
function addText(){
    ...
    localStorage.setItem('anchor'+c, input);
    c++;
    document.getElementById('do').appendChild(node);

}

function removeText(item){
    ...
    localStorage.removeItem(item);
}
```

**UPDATE**

To display the values from LocalStorage, I'd suggest you do a for loop to iterate through `localStorage.key(index)` and adding the text from there. [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cheejyg/Y83mQ/5/).

```
if (localStorage.length) {
    for (var index = 0; index < localStorage.length; index++) {
        var key = localStorage.key(index);
        var value = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(index));
    }
} else {
    //localStorage == null
}
```

Comment: This does not work on my end, It does not save if i refresh the page

Comment: @Triforce it does save (check http://jsfiddle.net/Cheejyg/Y83mQ/4/), it's just that there is no implementation for displaying them yet.

Comment: @Triforce updated JSFiddle which includes the displaying of values from LocalStorage. http://jsfiddle.net/Cheejyg/Y83mQ/5/

Comment: Ok it works on jsfiddle, but not if i try it on a webserver/localhost, might have no look in to that but do you know if jsfiddle is using any special script or something like that to make stuff works? sorry for my non understanding

Comment: @Triforce nope, it's working on my localhost so the problem might be at your end